# Don't return the entire row in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My SQLAlchemy code:

```
used_emails = list(db.execute(halo4.select(halo4.c.email != '')))
```

returns:

`[(80940L, 'P7J4H-DFDMG-G6HMJ-W7PF9-MDTF1', '1', 'first.last@domain.com', datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 3, 3, 48, 58)), (80939L, 'GCTFY-QPK2Y-PX1CJ-W69QY-PHDGZ', '1', 'first.last@domain.com', datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 3, 15, 8, 15)), (80938L, 'R4XGV-PG461-RGXX7-9R47R-2RWYZ', '1', 'first.last@domain.com', datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 3, 15, 8, 27))]`

How do I make SQLAlchemy only return:

`[('first.last@domain.com', 'first.last@domain.com', 'first.last@domain.com')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will give a list of the `email` column values:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select

used_emails = [row.email for row
               in db.execute(select([halo4.c.email], halo4.c.email!='')]
```

Basically you are telling the [`select()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) function to generate a `SELECT` statement for just the `email` column. The result of `execute()` will be a [`ResultProxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy) so the job of the [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is to create a list of `email` column string values from the single column rows obtained from the iterable [`ResultProxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy).

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works Pedro. This is the error I'm getting though `TypeError: select() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)` Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. We need the `select` function, not the `Table.select` method. Can you try the updated sample code? Thanks!